# Jekyll: incompatible character encodings: UTF-8 and Windows-874 (Encoding::CompatibilityError)

Tags: ruby, jekyll

how can I fix this issue. this error occur when I try to run local server with Jekyll. I expect that this error came from my file name. (when the file name had changed from Thai character to English character, none of the error occur).
So, Are there any way to fix this error without changing the file name?

[see the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uuAIg.png)

[see the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G6jnC.png)

Comment: Post the errors please

Comment: Please do not use external images to showcase the errors. Paste the errors in the question instead.